# end event fired immediatly after start on SpeechRecognition API

Tags: ubuntu, chromium, ubuntu-20.04, webspeech-api, webkitspeechrecognition

The `onend` callback is being called immediately after `start()` is called on SpeechRecognition, causing the voice recognition to never work:

```js
timestamp = Date.now()
speech = new webkitSpeechRecognition()
speech.onend = () => console.log('ended after', Date.now() - timestamp, 'ms')
speech.start() // immediately logs "ended"
```

[image: Log results]

This has been tested with **Chromium:** *Version 102.0.5005.115 (Build officiel) snap (64 bits)* on Ubuntu 20.04.

Am I missing something?

Comment: lol i'm again experiencing this issue, again stumbled upon this question and again upvoted but it tells me i already did half a year ago.